# atanh2 / " polar argument"

Tags: geometry

In many application you get a function of the form:

$$\tan(x) = \frac{f(A)}{g(B)}$$
Where you then have to use the "polar argument" (to account for all 4 quadrants):

$$\arg   \left( f(A), g(B) \right) $$
Often denoted as "atan2"  or arctan2 or similar in programming languages.

Now I wonder if the same applies to the hyperbolic functions, and how would a function then look like?

Given that $\tanh$ as:
$$\tanh(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$
$$\mathrm{atanh}(x) = 0.5 \cdot \ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there are no quadrants and $e^x$ is always positive.  The problem when you are doing $\arctan$ comes because the division can hide the sign combnation.